# Destroy all cookie in laravel not working

Tags: php, laravel, session, cookies, laravel-5

I use laravel 5.4 framework and I want to delete remember me cookie in laravel. I've tried various ways like `Session::flush()` `$request->session()->flush();` `$request->session()->regenerate(true);` `$this->driver->manage()->deleteAllCookies();` and `'expire_on_close' => true,` in **config/session.php**

```
$remembercokkie = Auth::guard('administrator');
$cokkie = Cookie::forget($remembercokkie);
return redirect('/')->withCookie($cookie);
```

but nothing happen still the user log in.
How do I fix this ?

Comment: What's wrong with a simple `Auth::logout()`?

Comment: I use that also for log out it work but when I check the remember me log out function not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To destroy a cookie, set it with a negative value for `$minutes` (the third argument).

```
return redirect('/')->withCookie(cookie('cookie_name', '', -1));
```

Source: http://coursesweb.net/laravel/cookies